# How to debug and detect hang issue

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, debugging, multiple-monitors, freeze

I am testing my application (Windows 7, WinForms, Infragistics controls, C#, .Net 3.5).
I have two monitors and my application saves and restores forms' position on the first or second monitors. So I physically switched off second monitor and disabled it at Screen Resolution on the windows display settings form. I need to know it is possible for my application to restore windows positions (for those windows that were saved on the second monitor) to the first one.

I switched off second monitor and press Detect to apply hardware changes.

[image]

Then Windows switched OFF the first monitor for a few seconds to apply new settings. When the first monitor screen came back, my application became unresponsive. My application was launched in debug mode, so I tried to navigate via stack and threads (Visual Studio 2008), paused application, started and did not find any thing that help me to understand why my application is not responsive.  Could somebody help my how to detect the source of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [Debugging Tools For Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) then run `adplus` in [hang mode](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2008/09/12/adplus-in-21-seconds-and-13-steps/).  The with the resulting .dmp file open in `windbg` and invoke:

```
!analyze -v -hang
```

Answer (score 1):

You should provide more information about what you saw in the call stack and threads windows.  Which threads were running?  Did you see anything that was waiting in a sleep or join?  Have you tried naming your threads so that it's clearer as to what's going on when you pause (though not necessary since you can get this info from the call stack anyway... it's a convenience thing).